# Span element keeps jumping to next line in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website in HTML & CSS using bootstrap.
Now I have this code which has no special CSS added to it except for the bootstrap one.

```
  <a href="/news" class="mr-3 mr-sm-5"><i class="fas fa-newspaper mr-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-block">Nieuws</span></a>
  <a href="/contact" class="mr-3 mr-sm-5 active"><i class="fas fa-headset mr-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-block">Contact</span></a>
```

But for some reason the Span element keeps jumping to the next line on the webpage.
Full code:

```
div class="containter-fluid full-nav">
    <div class="container py-2">
        <div class="row full-nav-links">
            <a href="/" class="ml-2 mr-5"><i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i> <span>Particulier</span></a>
            <a href="/zakelijk" class="mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-building mr-2"></i><span>Zakelijk</span></a>
            <a href="/news" class="mr-3 mr-sm-5"><i class="fas fa-newspaper mr-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-block">Nieuws</span></a>
            <a href="/contact" class="mr-3 mr-sm-5 active"><i class="fas fa-headset mr-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-block">Contact</span></a>
            <a href="/over-ons" class="mr-3 mr-sm-0"><i class="fas fa-star mr-2"></i><span class="d-none d-md-block">Over Stargroup</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the page it looks like this:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDmTP.png)

However, without the " d-none d-md-block " class added to the span object it looks fine (see first two links on the picture)

Please help, what do I need to do to prevent the SPAN element from jumping to the next line?

Comment: Have you use your browser's element-inspector to look at the style-rules for the `<a>`, `<i>` and `<span>` elements?

Comment: Also, you really should be using a `<nav>`, `<ul>` and `<li>` elements for a navigation list, imo.

Comment: @Dai These links are not the main navigation for the website, which is why they are not in a <nav> element :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `d-md-block` to `d-md-inline-block`.

You have `d-none` which makes the element disappear and then reappear on medium display and upwards with `d-md-block` but this forces the element to take up the whole width of the container and push anything else below it. `d-md-inline-block` does the job of making the element visible while not taking up the whole width of the container.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.